# Find part of word before caret in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery plugin that finds the caret position of a textarea. I implement it on the keyup function of the textarea, like this:

```
$("#editor").keyup(function () {
   var textbox = $(this);
   var end = textbox.getSelection().end;
});
```

I am wanting to find the word, or part of a word, before the caret. Words are delimited by any type of whitespace.

My main difficulty in doing this is dealing with line breaks. How can I find the word or part of a word immediately before the caret given the character index of the caret?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using [my jQuery textarea plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) for this, the selection character positions are always relative to the `value` property of the textarea, regardless of how the browser handles line breaks. You could then get the last word as follows:

Note that you have to use the textarea's `value` property and not jQuery's `val()` method, which normalizes line breaks.

```
$("#editor").keyup(function () {
    var textbox = $(this);
    var end = textbox.getSelection().end;
    var result = /\S+$/.exec(this.value.slice(0, end));
    var lastWord = result ? result[0] : null;
    alert(lastWord);
});
```

Comment: Damnit, I started looking at this but got distracted and you've already solved it! +1 as it's exactly the way I had done it. There is a small error though, `$textArea[0]` needs replacing with either  `$('textarea')[0]` or `this`.

Comment: @andyb: Ah yes, you're right (perils of copying and pasting). Fixed now, thanks.