# How can I get the text right before the cursor position starting from a contenteditable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, cursor-position

I have a contenteditable area and it may have something like

```
Hello @abc @my| it was nice to see you
```

The | is my cursor, and want to get the text from the '@' symbol nearest to the cursor to the cursor position, so in this case, I want to get '@my'. I have completely no idea how can I get the text backward from a position.

Comment: Seems to be a near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590706/find-part-of-word-before-caret-in-textarea

Comment: @skribe: No: the question you linked to applies to textareas, not contenteditable elements. They have different selection APIs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15157786/96100

Answer (score 0):

given the caret position as caretpos, and value of textbox as text

```
var result = /\S+@/.exec(text.slice(0, caretpos));
 var lastpos = result.length>0 ? result.lenth - 1:0;
var lastWord = result ? result[lastpos] : null;
```